# jquery returning XML values as one string instead of separate values

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a XML file which I'm loading in via jQuery, once the XML has loaded I read through the XML getting the values out. The problem I'm having is that the XML has a element called VAL, within that there is a child element also called VAL. So when I use:

```
var val = $(loadedElements[i]).find('val').text();
console.log("val = ", val);
```

I get all the val elements as one string, not separated as a parent and child.

Here is an example of the XML I'm working with:

```
<e>
    <name>myElement</name>
    <type>TEXT</type>
    <val>text to display</val>
    <acts>
        <act>
            <type>CLICK</type>
            <val>http://www.example.com</val>
        </act>
    </acts>
</e>
```

In this example XML when I output the val using `console.log("val = ", val);` I see:
val = 'text to display http://www.example.com'.

How can I separate out the two VAL elements?

Thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, should get you on you the right track:

```
$(loadedElements[i]).find('val').each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

or this:

```
var val = $(loadedElements[i]).find('val');
console.log($(val[0]).text());
console.log($(val[1]).text());​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/kvXvd/)